# scipy interpolate 2D data imported from file

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

This is the first time I will use python, scipy and all the concepts required for this task.

I have used Mathematica to calculate and display a very complex function in a 3D plot. Exporting from Mathematica is a real pain and never gives publication ready figures in a reasonable time frame. Gnuplot also is not very good with 3D plots therefore I through about using matplotlib. Reading through the documentation I see that all examples of plotting involve simple functions and variables defined as vector by the user. My first problem is as follows:

I can export the function data from Mathematica in a file with 3 tab separated columns (the separation can be something else if it helps!). First column is the x axis, second is y and third is z axis. What I need to plot basically is `z(x,y)`.

How does one import such data file for plotting?

The second question is: In order to obtain a smooth surface plot, do I need to perform some kind of interpolation of the data? If this is the case, then how can it be done with data imported from the file I described?

From this example [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html), the `scipy.interpolate.interp2d` function(?) needs two 1D vectors x and y and a 2D vector for z, in order to obtain an interpolated function `z(x,y)`.  But my data is x (first column) is 1D vector, y (second column) is 1D vector and z (third column) is 1D vector. 
The examples given there are a bit confusing to me because they use defined x and y vectors and a function for z which they then proceed to interpolate (i don't see the point of interpolation here).

I am hopping someone will point me in the right direction with this!

Comment: Load your file with [np.genfromtext](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), [Python's csv reader](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.reader), or [pandas csv reader](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table). Then upsample your data with [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#multivariate-data-interpolation-griddata).

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I will try to import with one of the suggested options. I am still confused about the interpolation. All examples use a function like f(x) to interpolate its values. I may not understand how this is supposed to work but this is not what I need. As I say the values of my function are on 3rd column in the file, while x and y are the first 2 columns. How can i obtain an interpolation for this case? I do not have a function with an expression I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need a defined function to employ [scipy's griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata). We can interpolate any given dataset, e.g., z = x² + y² + 1 with some data points removed:

```
0   0   1
1   0   2
3   0   10
0   1   2
1   1   3
2   1   6
0   2   5
1   2   6
2   2   9
3   2   14
0   3   10
2   3   14
3   3   19
```

The following code interpolates a 3D surface from these data points:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

#read data points from text file, could be also a csv reader
arr = np.genfromtxt("test.txt")
#extract x, y, z
x = arr[:,0]
y = arr[:,1]
z = arr[:,2]

#create figure with a 3D projection axis
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")

#number of data points per axis
n = 20
#upsample evenly along x and y axis
x_up = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), n)
y_up = np.linspace(np.min(y), np.max(y), n)

#create grid from these updsampled 1D arrays
x3d, y3d = np.meshgrid(x_up, y_up)
#interpolate z-values for this regular grid
#x, y, z are your original data points
#methods other than cubic are available
z3d = griddata((x, y), z, (x3d, y3d), method = "cubic")

#plot surface
ax.plot_surface(x3d, y3d, z3d)

#plot original data points on top
ax.scatter(x, y, z, color = "black", marker = "x", s = 50)

ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")
ax.set_zlabel("Z")

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: oh man this is brilliant! I will give this a try! thank you for clarifying things for me!

Comment: I tried your script but i get these weird errors: \numpy\core\_methods.py:29: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in reduce return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
numpy\core\_methods.py:26: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in reduce  return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
Traceback:
File "plot.py", line 25, in <module> x3d, y3d = np.meshgrid(x_up, y_up)
File "numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 4698, in meshgrid output = [x.copy() for x in output]
File "numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 4698, in <listcomp> output = [x.copy() for x in output]

Comment: Well, this happens, if you don't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your question. Step 1) Does the copy-pasted script with the sample data hard-coded into the script (x = [0, 1, 3, 0,...,2, 3], y = [0, 0, 0, 1,..., 3, 3]...) produce the output shown here?  Step 2) If you comment out everything between n = 20 and ax.plot_surface() including those lines, do you get a scatter plot of your data?

Comment: Sorry, it worked! Turns out my input file was faulty. I fixed it and it works! Now I have to beautify it! Thank you for your help!

Comment: That was the most likely reason, hence, my questions to distinguish between correctly reading the file and library version incompatibilities. Glad we sorted it out. Good luck with your project.