# How to plot 3D surface (colormap) in Python using Matplotlib, Pyplot with data including some blanks for certain (x,y) couples?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, interpolation

I have a peculiar data given in the table below.

| y | x | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 0 | - |
| 6 | 3 | - |
| 6 | 7.5 | 10.66 |
| 6 | 12 | - |
| 6 | 15 | - |
|  |  |  |
| 8 | 0 | 23.23 |
| 8 | 3 | 14.93 |
| 8 | 7.5 | 11.38 |
| 8 | 12 | 3.16 |
| 8 | 15 | 3.49 |
|  |  |  |
| 10 | 0 | - |
| 10 | 3 | 16.12 |
| 10 | 7.5 | 10.14 |
| 10 | 12 | 3.37 |
| 10 | 15 | - |
|  |  |  |
| 12 | 0 | - |
| 12 | 3 | - |
| 12 | 7.5 | 10.17 |
| 12 | 12 | - |
| 12 | 15 | - |

Basically, I need 4 smooth line plots each of which has different number of data points to merge in colorful 3D way smoothly. But as far as I know, it is **not** possible to merge lists with different length in a healthy way in Numpy, Python. The example code which I'm using is [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html)

Any suggestions?

Comment: But what does it mean for a surface plot that an x-y pair does not have a corresponding z-value?

Comment: That is what confuses me as well. But the data is as given. Let me give an example. In Mathematica you provide the data as triplets in spite of Python or any other programming language. If I could use Mathematica to plot this graph, Mathematica would do some smoothing internally which could work just fine (I guess).

Comment: But I cannot use Mathematica due to licencing issues.

Comment: As a starting point, I found this scipy-based answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51439808/8881141

Comment: I would happily share csv file if there were one. Given data is whole of it. As for Mathematica, it was **just** an example. (and it is quite normal for one to not know the specifics of algorithm of a licenced program, that is the very meaning of "closed source", right?) Please don't add insult to injury by mocking. Nevertheless, thanks for the link.

Comment: No mocking intended. Excel has so many stats problems, but people still use it for statistical calculations. I merely pointed out that one should be careful when using software, crosscheck what it says it does with actual results, and present raw data that reflect missing data points. That's all.

Comment: Were you successful in adapting the code or do you need help with it?

Comment: Unfortunately no. We used Mathematica.